# docker-compose selenium grid

Tags: selenium, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` version 2 to build a local selenium grid, and I'm running into trouble.

Most of my trouble is coming from a lot of old blogs/documentation and trying to build this using new documentation, with little practical reference (eg: no newer blogs). From my understanding, this should work but it's not.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  grid-hub:
    image: 'selenium/hub'
    ports:
      - '4444:4444'
  node-chrome-debug:
    image: 'selenium/node-chrome-debug'
    depends_on:
      - 'grid-hub'
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=grid-hub
```

Here's the output of my node, which never gets past this to register with the hub:

```
Waiting xvfb...
-bash: 169.254/16: No such file or directory
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
Waiting xvfb...
```

I've been scouring the `Dockerfile` on github, and I thought maybe I was missing an environment variable but I can't find what I'm missing.

Here's an update:
I've tried specifying the port via `- HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444`, but this has had no effect. I've opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/407) to increase visibility, but this also includes my docker version which I'll include here.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 08:47:51 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 08:47:51 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Comment: I'm not sure why xvfb won't start, but if you get past that you'll still need to add `HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444` otherwise the node won't be able to register with the hub

Comment: There's an open issue about a similar problem. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/pull/249

What environment is your docker host? And docker version?

Comment: @MarkLapierre, yeah I thought of that after the fact I just hadn't updated the question but it doesn't help

Comment: @MarkLapierre, I saw that one too. I'm not sure if it the same issue but I opened my own with this information to help with visibility. I'll update the question with the pertinent information

Comment: @MarkLapierre You were right. That linked issue will resolve the issue. I'll write up what I found. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment by `ddavison` from a [pending pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/pull/249)

On OSX, there are some environment variables being set that shouldn't be. By setting `no_proxy` we circumvent the issue.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  grid-hub:
    container_name: 'grid-hub'
    image: 'selenium/hub'
    ports:
      - '4444:4444'
  node-chrome-debug:
    image: 'selenium/node-chrome-debug'
    depends_on:
      - 'grid-hub'
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=grid-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - no_proxy=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the below docker-compose config

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.3
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.3
    shm_size: '3gb'
    depends_on:
      - hub
    links:
      - hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
```